# Display xml, css pages in a webview

Tags: android, xml, webview

I have a webview and i am trying to load a xml or css file in it - for example this one:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml

Now the xml is displayed in a very "ugly way" - all the values are being concatenated in a single string that fills the screen (unfortunately I cannot post a screenshot yet but just load the link in a webview, nothing fancy).

**Is there any way to display the xml (same with css) in a nice-formatted way like it is displayed in the browser?**